# How can I save images/videos in PHP (Laravel) to my Digital Ocean volume?

Tags: php, laravel, server, digital-ocean

I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is the right site to ask this, but I've written a website in PHP (Laravel) which is meant to take an image and video, save them in my Digital Ocean volume and store the image and video URLs in a MYSQL database. All while only making the image and video accessible to users authorized to view them (people shouldn't just be able to access the link).

I'm new to server setup related things such as this. I've tried Googling and searching on YouTube and other platforms but can't seem to find any tutorials. Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong thing due to my lack of knowledge.

I'm not necessarily looking to fix any code (hence why I've not posted any code). All I'm looking for is help in the above or a link to a tutorial. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to put this on a volume?  Why not use a Spaces/S3 bucket?  There is a nice API for this, you won't need to worry about managing volumes, and CDN service is included for free.  You would keep your objects private by default, and sign URLs to them for authorized users.

Comment: the first way is just install the laravel on the volume, the second way is set up path of filesystem to the volume

Comment: @Brad Oooh Spaces? Never heard of them. Thank you, will look into them, they sound like what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @Brad Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! I'm such a newb, should have seen this haha. Just need to figure out how to set it up and access it, but I guess it's a learning process.

Comment: @maxcodemachine You'll have an easier time looking for S3 tutorials.  Digital Ocean Spaces is a service compatible with AWS S3.  Fortunately, it's all just HTTP.  :-)  Most all the AWS S3 clients also work with Spaces.

Comment: have a look about this https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/introduction